# Unzipping Files using Loop Through a Dataframe that Defines Filepath

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, unzip

I have a data frame that contains all of my directory and sub-directory file paths. My first dataset contains the input 'path':

```
 Input: 
 \\data\A\New Jersey\Construction\2020.10.27\Results.zip
 \\data\A\New Jersey\Materials\2020.10.27\Results.zip
 \\data\A\Pennsylvania\Construction\2020.10.27\Results.zip
 \\data\A\Pennsylvania\Electrician\2020.10.27\Results.zip
```

My second dataset contains the 'output' path:

```
 Output:
 \\data\A\New Jersey\Construction\2020.10.27
 \\data\A\New Jersey\Materials\2020.10.27
 \\data\A\Pennsylvania\Construction\2020.10.27
 \\data\A\Pennsylvania\Electrician\2020.10.27
```

As you can see, I want the files unzipped to the same folder.  Currently I use a for loop without much success. Is this for loop incorrect?

```
 for(i in length(input)){
   for(f in length(output)){
      path <- input[i]
      out <- output[f]
      unzip(path, out) 
  }}
```

Answer (score 1):

create a list containing all files you want to unzip.
then you can just use lapply to unzip the whole list

```
  lapply(filelist, unzip) #or sapply for data frames
```

if you have a lot of files (and an ssd) you can use the `pbapply` library for the integrated progressbar (and multicore processing if you want) - without ssd multicoreprocessing seems slower than regular lapply - i assume it is because of read-write speeds of regular harddrives

```
pblapply(filelist, unzip)
```

for me it looks like this:

```
file_vec<-as.vector(filelist[1:5]) # my original filelist
file_vec # is a vector
sapply(file_vec, unzip)

     2020-08-01T000000_AIU-1936.ghg                 2020-08-01T003000_AIU-1936.ghg                 2020-08-01T010000_AIU-1936.ghg                
[1,] "./2020-08-01T000000_AIU-1936.data"            "./2020-08-01T003000_AIU-1936.data"            "./2020-08-01T010000_AIU-1936.data"           
[2,] "./2020-08-01T000000_AIU-1936.metadata"        "./2020-08-01T003000_AIU-1936.metadata"        "./2020-08-01T010000_AIU-1936.metadata"       
[3,] "./2020-08-01T000000_AIU-1936-biomet.data"     "./2020-08-01T003000_AIU-1936-biomet.data"     "./2020-08-01T010000_AIU-1936-biomet.data"    
[4,] "./2020-08-01T000000_AIU-1936-biomet.metadata" "./2020-08-01T003000_AIU-1936-biomet.metadata" "./2020-08-01T010000_AIU-1936-biomet.metadata"
     2020-08-01T013000_AIU-1936.ghg                 2020-08-01T020000_AIU-1936.ghg                
[1,] "./2020-08-01T013000_AIU-1936.data"            "./2020-08-01T020000_AIU-1936.data"           
[2,] "./2020-08-01T013000_AIU-1936.metadata"        "./2020-08-01T020000_AIU-1936.metadata"       
[3,] "./2020-08-01T013000_AIU-1936-biomet.data"     "./2020-08-01T020000_AIU-1936-biomet.data"    
[4,] "./2020-08-01T013000_AIU-1936-biomet.metadata" "./2020-08-01T020000_AIU-1936-biomet.metadata"
```

i have tried it with zip as well and it works - i just mostly use licor data hence the .ghg. i work with windows, the working directory is set to where the data is. i have little experience with linux/macOS but it should work the same

Comment: When I use the lapply statement I receive the following error: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : error 1 in extracting from zip file

Comment: what does your filename look like? i mean, do you have the full path or just relative path names?

Comment: "\\\\data\\A\\New Jersey\\Construction\\2020.10.27\\Results.zip"

Comment: Perhaps there is an issue with the list of filepaths? Is it possible to do this using a vector in a dataframe?

Comment: for me it does, ill add it to my answer

Comment: Thanks! The code runs, and R recognizes the contents of the Zip files and prints out the csv titles; however, they aren't actually unzipped and saved to the same folder. Are they being saved somewhere else?

Comment: To clarify, I want the files saved to the same subfolder that the zip file lives in.

Comment: they should be save to your working directory. you can try getwd() to see where you are. i just managed to recreate your error message. saved my file on D but set my wd to C (desktop) -> `setwd(where_your_files_are)` and it should work

Comment: Is there anyway to save the files to the same sub-folders that the zips files live?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223780/discussion-between-d-j-and-ldan).